# should all sessions be unset/removed in php

Tags: php, session

I know that the sessions exist until and unless the browser is closed or the session expires.I have a doubt that in case I have a session variable set which is of no use for any other part in the website.
So is it necessary to unset even this session variable.
Thank you.

Comment: Why you want a variable that is not of your use.

Comment: In technical parlance, there is only one "session", but many "session variables."

Comment: Also, please be more specific than "is of no use for any other part in the website." If a variable is only needed on one page, then it (usually) doesn't need to be a session variable.

Comment: what I mean by "is of no use for any other part in the website." is a session is needed only in some part and not others Thank you

Answer (score 0):

yes it is
reasons: it prevents the directory from filling up with session files that can cause performance to degrade and, more importantly, it reduces the risk of someone guessing session IDs and hijacking an old unused session

but PHP already have garbage collection for sessions so unused session variables are automatically cleaned up.

but for me its kind of a rule a unset any unused session variables immediately

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not necessary to unset session variables, but you can do it for those, which are not in use or needed to be unset as per business logic.

For example a shopping cart, user add some products and make the payment, after successful payment those products should be removed from card, hence needed to unset from session.

Answer (score -1):

To display all current session variables use `var_dump($_SESSION);`. There is no way to get the values of unset or destroyed session variables. For further reference please refer to the link. [Session Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)